# Background color not changing in HTML file

Tags: html, css, colors, background

first post here.

I was wondering why the background color is not changing.

I have the bg color property that is not working, apparently.

```
<body bgcolor="#f0ffff">
```

This is what I put as the body, and in CSS that's no mention of body whatsoever.

```
<head>
<title>User Settings</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MainStyles.css">
<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQueryMobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script src="JS\changeProfile.js"></script>
</head>
```

This it the heading of the HTML file, I don't know if this could be what's causing it.

Any help? I'm sorry but I'm quite new to this and it's really frustrating... If you need more info I will post more code.

Just gonna mention that there's no mention of background OR color in the HTML.

Comment: Works fine here: **http://jsbin.com/zifalexuci/edit?html,output**

Comment: <body style="background-color:#f0ffff;">

Comment: First: Where is `body` tag in your code ?  and Second: there might in a bady tag in your `MainStyles.css` file.

Comment: <body bgcolor="#f0ffff">

This is the start of the body tag

Comment: @PraveenKumar if that body tag not working on his html file then try body style

Comment: There's no body tag in MainStyles.css.

Might it be a problem with the other CSS imported? (jQuery)

Comment: @Klaast Could be the bootstrap theme overriding it. Don't use `bgcolor`. It's deprecated and old-school.

Comment: @MostafaBaezid You know what you did there. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar no man I have no idea what i am I doing. Please explain help him out and also please explain me. and why you smiling ?? :/

Comment: @MostafaBaezid You added `style`. Your solution actually works. `:)`

Comment: I tried with the style tag as well

<style>
 body {
 background-color: azure;
}
</style>

Comment: @Klaast Not style tag, just the inline style with body style. `:)`

Comment: ^ That doesn't work man.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the developer tools in your browser.
2. Inspect the body element.
3. Look at the styles that apply to it.

[image: DOM inspector]

`http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css` is changing the background colour of the `ui-overlay-a` class (which is, presumably, added to the body by jQuery Mobile when you load its JS).

Answer (score 0):

That is not working because `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css` contains a class which overriding `backhround-color` property.

See below:

[image: Css]